# Markov Chain that isn't Irreducible

Tags: markov-chains

What is an example of a Markov chain that isn't irreducible but has a unique distribution, such that its distribution converges to that unique invariant distribution for any initial distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest one: transition matrix $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.